# why do 'child' and 'descendant' give the same result in this domdocument() query?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to retrieve the text from within links in the following HEREDOC.

```xml
$html = <<<EOT
<a class="details" href="/link.asp">$2,697.75</a>
<a class="details" href="/link.asp"><s>$150.00</s></a>
<a class="details" href="/link.asp"><font color="red" size="2"><b>Price: $125.00</b></font></a>
EOT;
```

```php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$prices_nodeList = $xpath->query('//child::a[@class="details"]');
//$prices_nodeList = $xpath->query('//descendant::a[@class="details"]');
//$prices_nodeList = $xpath->query('//a[@class="details"]/descendant::text()');   

foreach ($prices_nodeList as $price) {
    $prices[] = $price->nodeValue;
}

echo("<p>prices</p>");
echo("<pre>");
print_r($prices);
echo("</pre>");

?>
```

The xpath query assigned to $prices_nodeList

```
$prices_nodeList = $xpath->query('//child::a[@class="details"]');
```

seems to do what I want, but I don't think I understand how it works. As far as I can understand, it says 'get all direct child elements of links with class "details".' However the text in the latter two links are not direct children, so I'm not sure why I don't have to use

```
$prices_nodeList = $xpath->query('//descendant::a[@class="details"]');
```

This (ie, the first commented-out value of $prices_nodeList) also retrieves all three values. I am wondering why they both work, and whether my query is actually the best way to do it. By contrast

```
$prices_nodeList = $xpath->query('//a[@class="details"]/descendant::text()');
```

works as well, but

```
$prices_nodeList = $xpath->query('//a[@class="details"]/child::text()');
```

only retrieves the first value ($2,697.75) and not the latter two (since the text is contained within elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I can understand, it says 'get all direct child elements of links with class "details".'

No, it means *get all links with a class "details" that are children of the current context nodes*.

The *context nodes* are the ones selected by the previous step.

`//` is a shortcut for `/descandant-or-self::node`. From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath):

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. For example, `//para` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select any para element in the document (even a `para` element that is a document element will be selected by `//para` since the document element node is a child of the root node); `div//para` is short for `div/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select all `para` descendants of `div` children.

`/descendant-or-self::node()` basically selects *every* node. Therefore there is no difference between looking at the `child` or `descendant` axis.

If a link is not the child of one node, it is surely the child of one of its descendants, which is selected by `//` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath, the pseudoperator `//` (short for `descendant-or-self::` axis) is used to select all nodes of a certain type, wherever they are  in the input tree. Then:

`//child::a` is the same as `//a`

and

`//descendant::a` is still equivalent to `//a`

You are always selecting all **a** nodes in the document, **wherever** they are.

---

While:

`//a/descendant::text()`, which is equal to `//a//text()`, means select all *descendant* text nodes of any **a** and it is different from

`//a/child::text()`, which equals to `//a/text()`, and means select all *child* text nodes of any **a** (`$2,697.75` only is child of **a**, the other text nodes are descendant).

---

In XPath explicit axis `descendant-or-self::` and `child::` are rarely used and necessary. The first one is normally substituted by `//` . The second one is implicitly applied in `/` or `//` as `/child::` or `//child::`.